# How to use query string parameters in SSRS Report 2012?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using BIDS Helper in a tabular project and I used a functionality to go from a Excel pivottable to a report with complete list of BI metrics. I already constructed the link as

http://reports.ABCDEFJ.net/ReportsDW/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fABCD+BI+Reports%2fDEV%2fDicion%c3%a1rio+de+Dados%2fR07+Dicionario+Dados&PRM_CUBE=01_CUBE_STOCK&rs:Command=Render

the link has a PRM_CUBE parameter with a cube to filter. My SSRS report already has a parameter PRM_CUBE with a combo box.

What do I need to do to link the PRM_CUBE parameter to the SSRS parameter/combox? The objective is naturally to:

- nothing selected on combo, nothing appears
- A is selected in the combo or sent via link, show it on combo and list associated values
- B is selected in the combo or sent via link, show it on combo and list associated values

At this moment the report completely ignores the query string parameter.